# How do I deploy Firefox Bookmarks for all Users in Network?

Tags: firefox, networking, bookmarks

I have a bash-script for installing Firefox which is downloaded and executed from every client workstation in the network. The script is on the server and all workstations are running Ubuntu. Now I want all workstations to have some default predefined bookmarks like company website etc. There is a way to do that by modifying the omni.jar file which is in the installation folder of Firefox but I could not find a working solution to do that.

How can I provide some bookmarks for all users?

Answer (score 1):

You will find your bookmarks in a private folder inside of  `.mozilla/firefox/` called places.sqlite - that holds the bookmarks. Copying this will also effectively copy your bookmarks. E.g., this is the location of my *places.sqlite* file - `/home/nits/.mozilla/firefox/me9d3dsc.default/places.sqlite`

More info from this [SOURCE](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_finding-your-profile-without-opening-firefox):

> **Finding your profile without opening Firefox(Ubuntu)**
>
> - Click the Places menu on the top right of the screen and select
>     Home    Folder. A File Browser window will appear.
> - Click the View menu and select Show Hidden Files if it isn't
>     already    checked.
> - Double click the folder marked .mozilla.
> - Double click the folder marked firefox. Your profile folder is
>     within    this folder.
>
> **What information is stored in my profile?**
>
> *Bookmarks and Browsing History:* The `places.sqlite` file contains
>   all your Firefox bookmarks and the list of all the websites you’ve
>   visited. For more information see Bookmarks.